# application Crash when assign multiple argu fun to dynamic button

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, selector

```
for (int i=0;i<[tableDataSource count];i++) 
{
        NSDictionary *dict = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:i];
        rowText = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setTitle:rowText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myActionbtnText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(60,  40+2*(40*i), 200, 40);
        btn.alpha = 0.81;

        [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

I got error at assign Action to dynamic button my action is given Below, how to pass object/parameter when button event occurs.

```
-(void) myAction:(NSString *)btnText; 
{
    NSLog(@"%@ Button Clicked",btnText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
for (int i=0;i<[tableDataSource count];i++)
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:rowText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myActionbtnText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.tag = i;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(60,  40+2*(40*i), 200, 40);
    btn.alpha = 0.81;

    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

-(void) myAction:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSDictionnary *dict = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSString* rowText = (NSString*)[dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"%@ Button Clicked",rowText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you MathieuF                                                    And it not scroll when button r increase in NO. Even i put it on ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your solution.

1. UIButton does not respond to `addTarget:action:withObject:forControlEvents:` but rather `addTarget:action:forControlEvents`. This is why your application is crashing.
2. The selector should be `@selector(myAction:)`. The parameter should not be included.
3. I'm pretty sure that it wouldn't work anyway since by the time the button is pressed `rowText` will be out of scope and no longer available. Which is why you should go with @MathieuF solution (Just make sure to specify the selector correctly).

Comment: Thank you Robert but if i have to pass parameter/argument to that function than what can i do. And it not scroll when button r increase  in NO. Even i put it on ScrollView.